# How can I send an array to Codeigniter with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I have an array of marks of students :

```
<span>Teacher Name : </span> <input id="teacher" type="text">
<span>Course Name : </span> <input id="course" type="text">
<table id="students_list">
    <tr>
        <td><span>George</span></td>
        <td><input class="mark-field" type="text" id="1105"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Danny</span></td>
        <td><input class="mark-field" type="text" id="1351"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Linda</span></td>
        <td><input class="mark-field" type="text" id="3486"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Mario</span></td>
        <td><input class="mark-field" type="text" id="9032"/></td>
    </tr>
    …
</table>
<button id="save_marks">SAVE</button>
```

I use this method to create an array with JQUERY and send it to server :

```
$(document).on('click', '#save_marks', function () {
    var dataArray = [];
    var i = 1;
    $('.mark-field').each(function () {
        dataArray[i] = {
            'teacher' : $('#teacher').val(),
            'course' : $('#course').val(),
            'mark' : $(this).val(),
            'id' : $(this).attr('id')
        };
        i++;
    });
    dataArray[0] = i;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save-marks',
        data: {dataset: dataArray},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
});
```

and use this way to change it to PHP (CodeIgniter) array and save it on database :

```
public function save_marks() {
    $arrayLength = $this->input->post('data')[0];
    for ($i = 1; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
        $arr[] = array(
            'TEACHERS' => $this->input->post('dataset')[$i]['teacher'],
            'COURSES' => $this->input->post('dataset')[$i]['course'],
            'MARKS' => $this->input->post('dataset')[$i]['mark'],
            'ID' => $this->input->post('dataset')[$i]['id']
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('marks_table', $arr);
    die($this->db->affected_rows() . ' marks were saved.');
}
```

Now my questions :

- Is there another way to calculate array length on the server side?
- Is it a good way to build an array both on the server side and on the client side?

  and if no
- Is there another way to create and send them to the server?

Thanks.

Comment: why you re-create an array if you already have ?

Comment: you can either converto to json and set those as string, or try using `data: {'dataset[]': dataArray},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Is there another way to calculate array length on the server side?**

Yes, by using `sizeof($array)`, you can get the array length of the array.

**2. Is it a good way to build an array both on the server side and on the client side?**

Using `name="mark-field[]"` you can send the mark list without manually construct it in your javascript, also by using `sizeof($array)` you can get array size in the server side without sending the size from your javascript.

**3. Is there another way to create and send them to the server?**

Personally, I would do something like this:

```
<form id = "form_data" method="post">
<span>Teacher Name : </span> <input id="teacher" name="teacher" type="text">
<span>Course Name : </span> <input id="course" name="course" type="text">
<table id="students_list">
    <tr>
        <td><span>George</span></td>
        <td>
            <input name="mark[]" type="text" id="1105"/>
            <input name="mark_id[]" type="hidden" value="1105"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Danny</span></td>
        <td>
            <input name="mark[]" type="text" id="1351"/>
            <input name="mark_id[]" type="hidden" value="1351"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Linda</span></td>
        <td>
            <input name="mark[]" type="text" id="3486"/>
            <input name="mark_id[]" type="hidden" value="3486"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="save_marks">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

and the javascript part

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_data', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        //fill url with your controller name
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>controllername/save_marks",
        method:"POST",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache:false,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(returndata)
        {
            //do something with your returned data
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

and in your controller:

```
public function save_marks() {
    $teacher= $this->input->post('teacher',true);
    $course= $this->input->post('course',true);
    //mark & mark_id is an array
    $mark= $this->input->post('mark',true);
    $mark_id= $this->input->post('mark_id',true);
    
    $arr = array();
    foreach($mark_id as $key => $row)
    {
        $arr[] = array(
            'TEACHERS' => $teacher,
            'COURSES' => $course,
            'MARKS' => $mark[$key],
            'ID' => $row
        );
    }
    
    $this->db->insert_batch('marks_table', $arr);
    //die($this->db->affected_rows() . ' marks were saved.');
    
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

By sending formdata, you wont need to manually construct the array, however since you need to send the `mark_id` to the controller, you need to add 1 more field to send the `mark_id`